# Getting an access to a variable after onDataChange has retrieved it

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an application which, at one point, retrieves a variable from the Firebase Database using `Query#addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` method. The code is as follows:

```
void initCurrentUserProfile () {
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    DatabaseReference userProfileReference =   mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users");
    userProfileReference = userProfileReference.child(mUser.getUid());

    Query userProfileQuery = userProfileReference.orderByKey();
    userProfileQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {


        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        // This is the variable that I want to get
        mUserProfile = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);
        }
...
```

I want to get an access to `mUserProfile`, which is a class with the user data right away in the `onCreate()` of my activity and load the picture the URL of which is contained within this `mUserProfile` variable.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    initCurrentUserProfile();
    Picasso.with(this).load(Uri.parse(mUserProfile.getProfilePicUrl())).into(mProfilePictureImageView);
}
```

The problem is, because of asynchronous nature of Firebase Database, I can't do it and get a `NullPointerException`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.grigori.fitnessapp.Profile.UserProfile.getProfilePicUrl()' on a null object reference
```

Do you have any suggestions as to what I might do in order to get access to this variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to call this line of code:

```
Picasso.with(this)
    .load(Uri.parse(mUserProfile.getProfilePicUrl()))
    .into(mProfilePictureImageView);
```

Right in the `onDataChange()` method and not in `onCreate()` method otherwise it will be always null.

The `asynchronous` behaviour means that the line above is called before you are trying to get the data from the database and that's why is always null.